# R maps and geosphere: connect cities without crossing international dateline

Tags: r, geospatial, geocoding, geosphere

I found this great tutorial on how to use maps and geosphere to connect points on a map in R using great circles:

https://flowingdata.com/2011/05/11/how-to-map-connections-with-great-circles/

Is there a way to make the lines go the other way if they run off the edge of the map (cross the international dateline):

[image: map]

My current code looks like this for a line connecting DC to Beijing:

```
library(maps) 
library(geosphere)

map("world")

lat_ca <- 38.89511
lon_ca <- -77.03637
lat_me <- 39.917
lon_me <- 116.383
inter <- gcIntermediate(c(lon_ca, lat_ca), c(lon_me, lat_me), n=50, addStartEnd=TRUE)# breakAtDateLine=TRUE) 


lines(inter)
```

to be clear, I would like to end up with something that looks like this:

[image: the long way around]

It seems like this would be the other arc of a great circle in the same plane as the first one but I can't figure out how to draw it.

Comment: Well, you wanted the shortest distance and you got it :) : `library(ggplot2); inter <- gcIntermediate(c(lon_ca, lat_ca), c(lon_me, lat_me), n=50, addStartEnd=TRUE, breakAtDateLine=T); ggplot(do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(inter), function(x) transform(as.data.frame(inter[[x]]), id=x))), aes(lon, lat, group=id)) + borders(fill="#333333") + coord_map("ortho", orientation=c(90, 0, 0)) + geom_line(color="red")`. Maybe you just need `map("world"); diagram::curvedarrow(c(lon_ca, lat_ca),  c(lon_me, lat_me), curve=.1)`?

Comment: Thanks!  this worked for what I was trying to do